# Network manager won't restart

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, atheros

I was browsing the web using Chrome when suddenly twitter gave up on me. Next I see no websites would return any response. But didn't look like a server/DNS issue. I tried to turn off my wifi so that I can reconnect but clicking 'Turn Off' in the top right system menu didn't help. Nothing happened. The wifi icon had changed to a question mark. I switched to command line and tried `/etc/init.d/network-manager`, `nmcli`, `ifdown`, `netplan` but all commands failed to respond. Meaning I would get no output at all and the process would keep running. Eventually had to kill the terminal after each command. Next I tried restarting my system but that got stuck too at a blank screen. Had to force power off.

After powering back on, this is what I found in syslog:

```
Jun 26 21:53:13 thinkpad kernel: [18847.039641] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: wmi command 16387 timeout, restarting hardware
Jun 26 21:53:13 thinkpad kernel: [18847.039662] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to set 5g txpower 20: -11
Jun 26 21:53:13 thinkpad kernel: [18847.039668] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to setup tx power 20: -11
Jun 26 21:53:13 thinkpad kernel: [18847.039674] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to recalc tx power: -11
Jun 26 21:53:13 thinkpad kernel: [18847.039746] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from 44:1c:a8:8e:b1:63 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun 26 21:53:13 thinkpad kernel: [18847.050831] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read hi_board_data address: -16
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.143678] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.143798] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144034] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to delete peer 44:1c:a8:8e:b1:63 for vdev 0: -108
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144183] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144276] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 842 at net/mac80211/sta_info.c:1094 __sta_info_destroy_part2+0x16a/0x190 [mac80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144278] Modules linked in: btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_conexant x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel thinkpad_acpi snd_intel_dspcfg intel_powerclamp nvram snd_hda_codec mei_hdcp ledtrig_audio snd_hda_core snd_hwdep coretemp snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq kvm_intel kvm btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq_device btbcm crypto_simd i915 videobuf2_common ath10k_pci videodev ath10k_core mc snd_timer btintel cryptd ath intel_xhci_usb_role_switch roles drm_kms_helper mac80211 cec snd rc_core bluetooth glue_helper cfg80211 mei_me libarc4 mei rapl ecdh_generic ecc intel_cstate ee1004 i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore joydev
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144366]  input_leds intel_pch_thermal wmi_bmof mac_hid efi_pstore serio_raw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid r8169 crc32_pclmul psmouse i2c_i801 sdhci_pci i2c_smbus realtek ahci cqhci xhci_pci sdhci libahci xhci_pci_renesas wmi video
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144413] CPU: 3 PID: 842 Comm: NetworkManager Not tainted 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144415] Hardware name: LENOVO 20H1004UIG/20H1004UIG, BIOS R0DET83W (1.83 ) 06/09/2017
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144467] RIP: 0010:__sta_info_destroy_part2+0x16a/0x190 [mac80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144474] Code: 24 1c 01 00 00 00 0f 84 45 ff ff ff 45 31 c0 b9 01 00 00 00 4c 89 e2 48 89 de 4c 89 ef e8 4e a2 ff ff 85 c0 0f 84 27 ff ff ff <0f> 0b e9 20 ff ff ff be 03 00 00 00 4c 89 e7 e8 82 e6 ff ff 85 c0
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144478] RSP: 0018:ffffbec9c0ab3930 EFLAGS: 00010282
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144483] RAX: 00000000ffffff94 RBX: ffff998a0d26e900 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144485] RDX: ffff998a0b560000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff998a0ef73228
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144488] RBP: ffffbec9c0ab3950 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000004
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144490] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9989842e8000
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144493] R13: ffff998a0ef707c0 R14: ffff998a0d26e900 R15: ffff998a0ef70df0
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144498] FS:  00007f294e4d2380(0000) GS:ffff998a13580000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144501] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144504] CR2: 0000083df9c5f000 CR3: 00000002f5444002 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144507] Call Trace:
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144560]  __sta_info_flush+0x128/0x180 [mac80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144624]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0xc0/0x5f0 [mac80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144683]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth+0x104/0x490 [mac80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144735]  ieee80211_deauth+0x18/0x20 [mac80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144805]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xb6/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144859]  cfg80211_mlme_down+0x66/0x80 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144911]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x127/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144924]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1e/0x20
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.144963]  __cfg80211_leave+0x133/0x1b0 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145001]  cfg80211_leave+0x2c/0x40 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145039]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x123/0x500 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145047]  ? asm_sysvec_call_function_single+0x12/0x20
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145055]  ? tun_build_skb.isra.0+0x3c0/0x3c0
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145062]  ? tun_device_event+0x25/0x3f0
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145070]  ? skb_dequeue+0x5f/0x70
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145080]  notifier_call_chain+0x4f/0x70
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145086]  raw_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145095]  call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x50/0x90
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145103]  __dev_close_many+0x63/0x110
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145110]  dev_close_many+0x85/0x130
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145118]  dev_close.part.0+0x44/0x70
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145126]  dev_close+0x18/0x20
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145164]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x77/0xd0 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145202]  cfg80211_rfkill_set_block+0x26/0x30 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145209]  rfkill_set_block+0x9b/0x150
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145214]  rfkill_fop_write+0x136/0x1e0
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145220]  vfs_write+0xc9/0x200
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145226]  ksys_write+0xb1/0xe0
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145232]  __x64_sys_write+0x1a/0x20
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145239]  do_syscall_64+0x49/0xc0
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145245]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145250] RIP: 0033:0x7f294f9422cf
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145257] Code: 89 54 24 18 48 89 74 24 10 89 7c 24 08 e8 29 fd ff ff 48 8b 54 24 18 48 8b 74 24 10 41 89 c0 8b 7c 24 08 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 2d 44 89 c7 48 89 44 24 08 e8 5c fd ff ff 48
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145260] RSP: 002b:00007ffe8aa7f800 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145265] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055ae2477e5c5 RCX: 00007f294f9422cf
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145268] RDX: 0000000000000008 RSI: 00007ffe8aa7f838 RDI: 000000000000001a
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145271] RBP: 000000000000001a R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145273] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 000055ae25856030
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145276] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 000055ae25850420
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.145284] ---[ end trace a042d33586c47ca3 ]---
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.146452] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.146459] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad kernel: [18847.146465] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to set erp slot for vdev 0: -108
Jun 26 21:53:14 thinkpad wpa_supplicant[878]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=44:1c:a8:8e:b1:63 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jun 26 21:55:01 thinkpad CRON[30248]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660730] INFO: task wpa_supplicant:878 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660743]       Tainted: G        W         5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660747] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660752] wpa_supplicant  D    0   878      1 0x00000000
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660760] Call Trace:
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660783]  __schedule+0x394/0xa60
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660794]  ? ttwu_do_activate+0xb2/0x3e0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660804]  schedule+0x55/0xc0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660813]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660822]  __mutex_lock.isra.0+0x17d/0x4e0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660839]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660847]  mutex_lock+0x32/0x40
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660854]  rtnl_lock+0x15/0x20
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660932]  nl80211_pre_doit+0x104/0x1b0 [cfg80211]
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660942]  genl_rcv_msg+0x184/0x320
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660951]  ? genl_start+0x140/0x140
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660958]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x50/0x120
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660965]  genl_rcv+0x29/0x40
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660971]  netlink_unicast+0x1a8/0x250
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660978]  netlink_sendmsg+0x221/0x440
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660989]  sock_sendmsg+0x65/0x70
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.660997]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x218/0x290
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661005]  ? copy_msghdr_from_user+0x5c/0x90
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661014]  ? fsnotify_grab_connector+0x51/0x90
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661022]  ? fsnotify_destroy_marks+0x27/0xf0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661031]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x81/0xc0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661041]  ? evict+0x14c/0x1b0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661049]  ? iput+0x1a3/0x210
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661059]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661071]  ? __cgroup_bpf_run_filter_setsockopt+0xae/0x2d0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661078]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661087]  __sys_sendmsg+0x62/0xb0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661098]  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1f/0x30
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661108]  do_syscall_64+0x49/0xc0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661115]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661122] RIP: 0033:0x7f8391f59747
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661127] RSP: 002b:00007ffed2e16ec8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661134] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00005597437a4700 RCX: 00007f8391f59747
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661137] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffed2e16f00 RDI: 0000000000000006
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661140] RBP: 00005597437fe310 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 00007f8392021b80
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661144] R10: 00007ffed2e16fd4 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00005597437a4610
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661147] R13: 00007ffed2e16f00 R14: 00007ffed2e16fd4 R15: 00005597437e64d0
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661237] INFO: task ThreadPoolForeg:29008 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661245]       Tainted: G        W         5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661249] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661253] ThreadPoolForeg D    0 29008   2266 0x00000000
Jun 26 21:55:17 thinkpad kernel: [18970.661259] Call Trace:
....
```

In the past few days, my system has been freezing sometimes. I'm not sure if it's due to the network each time but I'd like to dig in deeper. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty obvious that you've got a crash in your network driver. Either your hardware gave up or a recent update (kernel or firmware) does not work with your device. Check the lines below : `Call trace:`

Comment: Thanks @kanehekili. There are 9 call traces in total. Anything specific that I should be looking for? Also checked apt logs. Kernel was updated a day ago to 5.8.0-59-generic.